# Is there a standard text for parachute design?

Tags: parachute

In some technology areas, there are "standard" texts - for GA type aircraft design, I think of Stinton's "Design of the Airplane". For radar, Skolnik's "Radar Handbook".

Is there an equivalent text for parachute / para-airfoil design?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some useful texts are [The Aerodynamics of Parachutes](http://ftp.rta.nato.int/public//PubFullText/AGARD/AG/AGARD-AG-295///AGARDAG295.pdf) by Cockrell, [Ram Air Parachute Design](https://info.aiaa.org/tac/AASG/ADSTC/RamAir%20Parachute%20Design/Forms/AllItems.aspx) by Lingard, and the Parachute Recovery Systems Design Manual by Knacke.  The Lingard and Cockrell papers both have extensive references that are worth pursuing.  The Knacke manual is, as far as I know, only available in hardcopy.

It seems that the designers of modern sport ram-air parachutes and paragliders are more concerned with protecting trade secrets than they are in publishing research.  The paragliding side of the aisle is a bit more willing to share.  There is an online [paraglider design handbook](http://laboratoridenvol.com/paragliderdesign/index.html), and there are several open source paraglider CAD software packages available.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like there is a copy of Knacke available at http://oai.dtic.mil/oai/oai?verb=getRecord&metadataPrefix=html&identifier=ADA247666 - a reputable site, but not the clearest copy.